# Angular - How To remove the elements from ngFor

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-template

I am having a Array which has a structure like this:

```
Names : ["X","y","","Z"];
```

I have a *ngFor Iterator that display the array elements. I want that - the empty element in the array to be ignored and print output like this :

```
 1. X
 2. Y
 3. Z
```

The issue is when I use this code:

```
<div*ngFor="let child of Names; let bpiIndex = index" class="sub-title _h4">
   <span *ngIf="child">{{bpiIndex + 1}}.{{child}}</span>
</div>
```

it generates the output like :

```
1. X
2. Y
4. Z
```

is there a way that I can control the index so that It can omit the null or empty values in the array (Given that I am trying to do this in template)?

Comment: Create a `pipe` or remove the empty values from `Names` in your `.ts`

Comment: pipe would not be cost effective for the thing of this magnitude. I think splicing the array is the only good option. Thanks @xyz

Comment: @vaibhav the effectiveness of the pipe isn't in question there, there's 4 items. the real question is should you keep the null value in the array, and display only the non-null values, or simply change the dataset and remove the value from the array.

Comment: Yes @trichetriche. I am just looking for the most efficient way to do that.

Comment: You have 4 results, don't worry, anything will be efficient :)

Comment: Hehe, this is a sample response. :D Actual one is going to be a bit big. But that won't matter much too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using the actual index when you should just instantiate a new variable.

> let bpiIndex = index

instead of this **instantiate** bpiIndex **to 0** and use **var** so the value stays between loops

```
var bpiIndex = 0
```

You can also buffer a second array filtered by names, so if the values don't have a name they won't be part of the second array and render this new list.

```
CurrentArray : string[] = ["X","y","","Z"];
...
ngOnInit() {
  this.BufferArrayNoNull = this.CurrentArray.filter(i=>i);
}
```

Comment: Can be used, just that there will be an additional variable.

Answer (score 2):

Simply after you get the value just run filter method like this

```
Names : string[] = ["X","y","","Z"]; // this set the value and the type
...
ngOnInit() {
  this.Names = this.Names.filter(i=>i); // falsy value will removed
}
```

if you got the value by http request use map rxjs operators

```
this.service(...)
 .pipe(map( result => result.filter(i=>i)))
 .subscribe(result => this.Names = result )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.names = this.names.filter((name)=> {
if(name != '') {
return true
}
}) // ["x", "y", "z"]
```

so it will result as you expected output

```
// 1.X

     2.Y

     3.Z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) your "Names" list to just hold relevant values. If you need these empty values in the array you has to create the same filter just for output via [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) or an extra filtered array and use it for output only.